# The startActivity () method returns an error. / Fragment - Android

Tags: java, android, start-activity

I have two classes that are covered by fragment.

The startActivity () method returns an error.

When my button named btn in my home.java class is clicked.
  I want to click on my button named btnctwo in my class named hometwo.java.

but i get an error.

logcat

```
 .sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp.hometwo}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Do I need to add my hometwo.java class to my AndroidManifest file as in the sample code below?

```
<activity  
         android:name=".hometwo"  
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I added my hometwo.java class to my AndroidManifest file as in the code example I mentioned above.
But I got an error.

Why do I need to add my hometwo.java class to my AndroidManifest file?

home.java

```
public class home extends Fragment {
    Button btn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        tn =  rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnc);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), hometwo.class);
                intent.putExtra("Indicator", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

hometwo.java

```
public class hometwo extends Fragment {
    Button btnctwo;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        btnctwo =  rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnctwo);

        Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            if (b.containsKey("Indicator"))
                btnctwo.performClick();
        }

        btnctwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("testler","testlertwo");
            }
       });
       return rootView;  
    }
}
```

logcat

```
2020-05-17 16:21:10.944 9826-9826/com.sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp, PID: 9826
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp/com.sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp.hometwo}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2049)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1709)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:791)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:933)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1185)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1173)
        at com.sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp.home$1.onClick(home.java:29)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: that's not how you start a fragment. you're trying to start a fragment as an activity, which it isn't

Comment: hello home.java and hometwo.java my classes work in navigation drawer. I couldn't understand exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no answer to this question.

> that's not how you start a fragment. you're trying to start a fragment
>   as an activity, which it isn't @a_local_nobody

The startActicity () method does not work in a class extended by fragment.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), hometwo.class);
        intent.putExtra("Indicator", true);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks @a_local_nobody